# MapKit's 'style' parameter in the request

Tags: parameters, get, mapkit

I'm debugging one application and I found a strange parameter in the requests
The request is something like :

*gspe15.ls.apple.com/tile.vf?flags=1&**style=13**&size=2&scale=0&v=234&z=14&x=12205&y=1853&checksum=1&sid=&accessKey=*

but I'm interested particularly in the "style" parameter. What means that parameter, where I can find more info about the values that can be passed ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mktileoverlaypath?language=objc
Check this out, it seems to be linked with MapKit

Comment: Yes, but nothing related to this topic... I can't believe nobody cares, and most important - there is undocumented parameters in such common application.